# How to check if a Java class contains JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit, junit4, junit3

I have to check if a certain `Class<?>` object contains JUnit tests (both JUnit3 and JUnit4).

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/133242). What bigger goal are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MattBall I have a list of `Class<?>` objects that I need to instrument, but I need to filter out the JUnit test cases.

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I don't think that answers the JUnit3 part of my question.

Comment: How about JUnit4 part?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov your comment is helpful, but the part about duplication is invalid due to JUnit3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Java reflection on the classes to find out.

For version 3 the class must extend TestCase.

For version 4 you can scan for annotations, see this: [How to get annotations of a member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453159/how-to-get-annotations-of-a-member-variable)

Basically you have to do as if you were JUnit, maybe you can even reuse some of the existing JUnit code.