# Get list of fields with annotation, by using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I create my annotation

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

I put it on fields in my test object

```
public class TestObject {

    @MyAnnotation 
    final private Outlook outlook;
    @MyAnnotation 
    final private Temperature temperature;
     ...
}
```

Now I want to get list of all fields with `MyAnnotation`.

```
for(Field field  : TestObject.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class))
        {
              //do action
        }
}
```

But seems like my block do action is never executed, and fields has no annotation as the following code returns 0.

```
TestObject.class.getDeclaredField("outlook").getAnnotations().length;
```

Is anyone can help me and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I & proper names like Java, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get annotations of a member variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453159/how-to-get-annotations-of-a-member-variable)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to mark the annotation as being available at runtime. Add the following to your annotation code.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

Comment: It's correct. But, I thought the Annotation is for runtime use.

Comment: @wrivas Not all annotations are for runtime. For example `@SuppressWarnings` is RetentionPolicy.SOURCE since it just a hint to the compiler to not warn about certain things.

Comment: Annotations are for Source only (for you to read), Compile time or Runtime

Comment: This is such a non-obvious requirement. I wish I could give more than one thumbs-up.

Answer (score 19):

```
/**
 * @return null safe set
 */
public static Set<Field> findFields(Class<?> classs, Class<? extends Annotation> ann) {
    Set<Field> set = new HashSet<>();
    Class<?> c = classs;
    while (c != null) {
        for (Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(ann)) {
                set.add(field);
            }
        }
        c = c.getSuperclass();
    }
    return set;
}
```

Comment: Apache Commons has this functionality: FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(...)