# getAnnotations() empty

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following code:

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

and this **failing** test:

```
@MyAnnotation
private Object obj = new Object();

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(1, obj.getClass().getAnnotations().length);
}
```

resulting in:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added the annotation to the `Field` in your class not the `Object` class. Try

```
Field field = getClass().getDeclaredField("obj");
MyAnnotation ma = field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
assertNotNull(ma);
assertEquals(1, field.getAnnotations().length);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the correct answer, but how would you go about not using `getDeclaredField`? I mean, is there any way to naturally pass a “special” annotated object without resorting to reflective functions?

Comment: @gurghet `Class`, `Method`, `Field` are all part of reflection. You can read the raw byte code to find the annotation (and some tools do this) but this is a lot harder.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [How to get annotations of a member variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453159/how-to-get-annotations-of-a-member-variable).

`obj.getClass()` returns in your case `java.lang.Object` that does not have any annotations.