# Read value of an Annotated Filed in Java

Tags: java, android, annotations

I'm using custom annotations in my App. I have a requirement where I need to read the value of an annotated field using reflection. For example

```
    @CheckNull
    String name;
```

I can have fileds declared like this. So, in some other class where I process this annotation, I need to read value of `name` field,

Is it possible?

Please don't make it duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453159/how-to-get-annotations-of-a-member-variable) Because, as per the accepted answer

```
for(Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()){
  Class type = field.getType();
  String name = field.getName();
  Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
 }
```

It reads the `type` , `name` of the field and the annotations present in the field. My requirement is different. Say, if I have a field

```
   @CheckNull
   private String name;
```

And if someone has assinged it a value

```
     name = "doe";
```

What I need to read is the value "doe". Not the annotatios, type or filed name

Comment: sure, you can iterate through all fields, and check if the field is annotated with your annotation. Then you can read the field value with reflection

Comment: Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldValues.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#method_summary

Comment: The accepted answer is a combination of two of the duplicates.